# Directional derivative for differentiable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

In the directional derivative formula
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = \nabla f \cdot v$$

why must $v$ be a unit vector?

Comment: because a unit vector is sufficient to give a 'direction'; this is just a definition

Comment: What if I use another vector with the same direction, why is the result wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $v$ does not have to be a unit vector. But if $\|v\| = 1$, then $\|v\|$ doesn't artificially affects our geometric interpretations. In more general contexts (e.g., differential geometry), we define the gradient of $f$ in $p$ as the vector ${\rm grad}\, f(p)$ verifying $${\rm d}f_p(v) = \langle {\rm grad}\,f(p), v\rangle, \quad \forall v$$That is, we think "backwards". In $\Bbb R^n$, we have ${\rm grad}\,f(p) = \nabla f(p)$.